# Reduce boilerplate with RepositoryPattern

Tags: c#, repository

I'm refactoring a WPF application that uses Repository pattern to access the web services, I've got a tons of repository wrote as

```
public class DiagnosticsRepository : DefaultRepositoryBase, IDiagnosticsRepository
{
    public Task<IList<MasterDiagnosticType>> GetMasterDiagnosticTypes(string username)
    {
        var client = GetServiceStackClient();

        var request = new MasterDiagnosticTypesRequest
        {
            UserName = username
        };

        return client.PostAsync(request);
    }

    public Task<IList<MasterDiagnostic>> GetMasterDiagnosticsFromType(int type)
    {
        var client = GetServiceStackClient();

        var request = new MasterDiagnosticRequest()
        { MasterType = type };

        return client.PostAsync(request);
    }

    public Task<DiagnosticoDataResponse> GetMasterDiagnostic(string storedProcedure)
    {
        var client = GetServiceStackClient();

        var request = new DiagnosticoDataRequest()

        {
            StoredProcedureName = storedProcedure,
            Data = DateTime.Today
        };

        return client.PostAsync(request);
    }
}
```

How can I review it so that I can avoid the repetition? the only part that changes is the request

Comment: I assume you meant 'refactoring' instead of 'reviewing'?

Comment: you're right, fixing title

Comment: I think you need first refactor `PostAsync`. As I can see from your code this method can return many different types. I suggest to generalize return type of this method with kind of `IPostResponse`. As for parameter of the method I would define it as `IPostRequest`. And all request types should implement this interface. After these changes refactoring of repositories will be trivial.

Comment: PostAsync is from ServiceStack

Comment: I am not sure but it seems that you can specify type of the response via generic type parameter of the method like `PostAsync<IPostResponse>`. I didn't work with ServiceStack but it looks configurable.

Comment: ok but my problem is is there a way I can refactor this code to write less code?

Comment: "I've got a tons of repository wrote as" show at least one more, so we maybe can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must keep the code the same way, I can think of only reducing the repeated

```
var client = GetServiceStackClient();
return client.PostAsync(request);
```

by doing something like this:

```
public class DiagnosticsRepository : DefaultRepositoryBase, IDiagnosticsRepository
{
    public Task<IList<MasterDiagnostic>> GetMasterDiagnosticsFromType(int type)
    {
        var request = new MasterDiagnosticRequest()
        {
            MasterType = type
        };

        return Refactor<IList<MasterDiagnostic>, MasterDiagnosticRequest>.Get(request);
    }

    public Task<DiagnosticoDataResponse> GetMasterDiagnostic(string storedProcedure)
    {
        var request = new DiagnosticoDataRequest()
        {
            StoredProcedureName = storedProcedure,
            Data = DateTime.Today
        };

        return Refactor<DiagnosticoDataResponse, DiagnosticoDataRequest>.Get(request);
    }

    // get rid of the repetition... 
    private class Refactor<TRespone, TRequest>
    {
        public static Task<TRespone> Get(TRequest request)
        {
            var client = GetServiceStackClient();
            return client.PostAsync(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, I don't think you should have all these various methods and signatures at all. You could reduce the repository to just the methods that are usually found in a repository (ex: Add, Update, GetById, Delete, Etc...

Which would mean your repository would potentially just look like this instead:

```
public class DiagnosticsRepository<T> : IDiagnosticsRepository
{
    public static Task<T> Get(object request = default(object))
    {
        var client = GetServiceStackClient();
        return client.PostAsync(request);
    }
}
```

*-The below is unconfirmed for your particular library, but based on my quick read of the documentation, this should work-*
With the above minimized repository,  if you like, you could go even further and swap your requests to anoymous types to reduce the amount of classes you are generating -- which is not uncommon especially for JSON requests. For example:

```
string storedProcedure = "...";
object request = new { StoredProcedureName = storedProcedure, Data = DateTime.Today };
var response = DiagnosticsRepository<DiagnosticoDataResponse>.Get(request);
```

Comment: I've not got spurce here... btw i was thinking of a Func<TResponse> in the base class...your approach of a static method is the same? Unfortunately I don't have CRUD operation... and access is 90% via StoredProcedures

Comment: I don't think you will make your code any easier to understand by adding more layers into your classes. I'd take a look at how to pass the generic types into `.PostAsync<T>()`and refactor based on that rather than using all these helper methods like `XyzRequest()`

Comment: xyzRequest are POCO used by ServiceStack to perform calls

Comment: @advapi - I'm certain it can be refactored... Have you tried sending an anonymous type on the request? Ex: `new { Prop = val }` instead of `new XyzRequest { Prop = val }`? -- If I am right, we just saved you from at least double the classes you're writing.

Comment: no Ive not... the advantage of this is that I've the POCO on the server side

Comment: @advapi -- i've added a sample for you to see at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks but on the server side servicestack expects a public objecy Any(DiagnosticoDataRequest request)

Comment: It was worth a try.